# One-Sided Binomial Test: How sure are we of a success rate?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

A mouse is performing a task in which chance level is 50%. It performs 100 trials of which 60 are correct. How sure can we be that it learned the task?

Any enlightenments?

Comment: You need to define "learned the task". If we consider only two possibilities, i.e. "learned the task": p=1, "didn't learn the task": p=1/2, then we can be 100% sure that it didn't learn it, because if so we would have had 100 successes.

Comment: To understand how sure are we of that success rate, you could find the maximal/minimal p, such that 60 will be included when sorting all outcomes w.r.t. their probability given that p, and selecting the most probable outcomes up to 95% total probability mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change it to "how sure we can be that the mouse learned *something.*"
That is, we test $H_0: p = .5$ [ignorant mouse performing at random] vs.
$H_a: p > .5$ [trained mouse is correct more often than not]. With $n = 100$
and $X = 60$ correct performances, the mouse's proportion correct is
$\hat p = X/n = 60/100 = 0.6.$

With $n = 100$ trials, it is safe to use a normal approximation, with
test statistic $Z = \frac{\hat p - .5}{\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}},$
and rejecting $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance if $Z > 1.645.$

In your case, $Z = \frac{.1}{\sqrt{.24/100}} = 2.04124 > 1.645,$ so we conclude
that the mouse has done significantly (if not spectacularly) better than random.

Here is Minitab 17 output for this procedure (slightly edited for relevance).
The P-value < 0.05 indicates significance at the 5% level.

```
Test of p = 0.5 vs p > 0.5

Sample   X    N  Sample p  Z-Value  P-Value
1       60  100  0.600000     2.00    0.023

Using the normal approximation.
```

The figure below shows the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(n=100, p=.5)$ along
with the density curve of the 'best-fitting' normal curve. The P-value
of the test is the probability to the right of the dotted red line.

[image]

*Note:* An 'exact test' (not using a normal approximation) would get the P-value 0.028 by summing the heights of the binomial bars at and above 60. (Computation uses R statistical software.)

```
1 - pbinom(59.5, 100, .5)
## 0.02844397
```